# Matlab: Comparing 2 images with different dimension and pixel size

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I have 2 images that I need to compare:

Image 1: size [512 x 512] with pixel dimension: 0.41 mm

Image 2: size [210 x 210] with pixel dimension 1 mm
I tried to use: `imresize`

```
imresize(Image_1, [210 210]) % to change size/pixel
```

However it reduce the resolution and image is not clear at all.
Any suggestion will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have that problem with comparing two images of different resolutions. I would do a pre-processing of images to make them comparable, maybe something more than just making them of the same size. That pre-processing really depends on your images.

Anyway, perhaps it would be better to re-size the smaller one to a larger version using one of the methods mentioned here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html and then compare them. For example, I would enlarge the smaller image using 'lanczos3' method.

```
imresize(Image_2,[512 512],'lanczos3');
```

Comment: I would advise against resizing the smaller one to a larger dimension as you'd be introducing interpolation artifacts.  I would rather resize the larger one as you aren't introducing new information (or very little).  The only time you could get away with resizing smaller to larger is if you are creating a scale-space, but there are a particular set of conditions you need to meet if you want to do this properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right it would introduce some interpolation artifacts but as I said in my answer it really depends on the images. I have had some good results with enlarging the dimensions, although most of the times just changing the dimensions did not work out. That is why I said you need to do some pre-processing on the image(s).

Comment: Oh I missed that.  My apologies!

Comment: It is alright, mate. You brought up a good point. That's is why I think more information of the images is needed to give a more precise answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks,This might be dirty, but quick comparison. I will definitly try this.

Answer (score 2):

if you meant to test if the two images are identical, instead of resizing the images, you can use filters with different bandwidths. or a higher level feature, such as sift feature, can usually take care of sizing issues because it picks the most interesting scale internally.

vlfeat is a good toolbox if you use matlab.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into VLfeat toolbox.